# Der Unterschied zwischen einem Vorgehen und Verfahren

Tags: difference

Der Duden legt das Vorgehen als eine *Vorgehensweise* aus. Doch wenn man auf die Bedeutung des Verbs *vorgehen* schaut, da steht einfach *verfahren* drin.

Gibt es überall einen Unterschied zwischen einem "Vorgehen" und einem "Verfahren" oder haben sie genau denselben Sinn?

Comment: das Vorgehen und das Verfahren _können_ sich auf unterschiedliche Dinge beziehen, genauso wie Regen und Niederschlag - und genau wie die beiden, gibt es Fälle in denen man das eine Wort gegen das andere tauschen kann, ohne dass sich der Sinn eines Satzes ändert. Könntest du einen Kontext vorgeben?  ---- Wäre das Verfahren zum Beispiel ein Gerichtsverfahren - dann kann nicht einfach "Vorgehen" eingesetzt werden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Hauptunterschied ist, dass bei einem "Verfahren" der Ablauf formal definiert ist (Gerichtsverfahren, Herstellungsverfahren, Bankverfahren). "Vorgehen" ist hingegen die konkrete Ausprägung von (zweckorientierten) Handlungsweisen (ggf. auch nur geplant) unabhängig von einer formalen Definition.

Z.B.:
"Ihr Vorgehen widersprach in jeder Hinsicht dem üblichen Verfahren."

"Das Vorgehen des Schalterbeamten, wenn ein Kunde Geld einzahlen will, ist im Bankverfahren beschrieben."

Bei der Verwendung als Verb verschiebt sich der Bedeutungsunterschied etwas und "vorgehen" bekommt mehr Konnotation von (strategischer) Planung, aber in Hinblick auf eine recht eng gefasste, konkrete Situation und beschreibt eher den allgemeinen Handlungsmodus ("Wie gehen wir vor?" "Wir sollten vorsichtig vorgehen.") oder steht im Sinne von "vorgehen gegen etwas" mit einem Objekt ("Die Machthaber gingen rücksichtlos gegen Rebellen vor.").

"verfahren" als Verb steht entweder allein als komplett offene Frage nach dem weiteren Vorgehen ("Wie verfahren wir weiter?") oder bezieht sich i.d.R. auf ein Objekt ("Wie verfahren wir mit den Eindringlingen?").

Comment: Der Schalterbeamte folgt eher einem *Verfahren* als einem *Vorgehen* (weil er das für alle Bankkunden genau gleich macht). Das Beispiel ist nicht besonders gut gewählt.

Comment: Das Beispiel habe ich bewusst so gewählt, dass beides auftaucht, um den Kontrast zu veranschaulichen (Das (Bank-)Verfahren beschreibt das Vorgehen des Beamten).

Answer (score 3):

### Verfahren

Ein Verfahren ist eine erprobte und etablierte Abfolge von Einzelschritten, die in ihrer Gesamtheit die Bewerkstelligung einer klar definierten Aufgabe ergeben.

Beispiele:

- In einem **Gerichts-Verfahren** wird ein juristischer Sachverhalt geklärt und bewertet, und die dafür vorgesehenen Schritte sind genau in Gesetzen, Verordnungen und ähnlichen Dokumenten vorgegeben.
- Das **Haber-Bosch-Verfahren** ist eine industriell anwendbare Abfolge von Tätigkeiten, die geeignet ist Ammoniak herzustellen.
- Das **Additions-Verfahren** ist eine Folge einfacher Schritte, mit denen man in der Mathematik die Lösungen von Gleichungssystemen finden kann.

---

### Vorgehen

Ein Vorgehen ist zwar auch eine Abfolge von Einzelschritten, mit denen ein vorher bekanntes Ziel erreicht werden soll, aber ein Vorgehen ist meist weder erprobt noch etabliert. Ein Vorgehen ist - im Gegensatz zum Verfahren - meist auch etwas einmaliges.

Der Begriff »Vorgehen« wird häufig dann verwendet, wenn das Ziel nicht erreicht wurde, oder wenn es mit unerwünschten Seiteneffekten erreicht wurde.

Beispiele:

- Rohani rügt das **Vorgehen** der Sittenwächter
- Das **Vorgehen** von Merkel in der Flüchtlingsfrage wurde vielfach kritisiert

Dazu ist anzumerken, dass meinen Recherchen zufolge vor allem in der Schweiz das Wort **Vorgehen** vollinhaltlich als Synonym von **Verfahren** verwendet wird.

---

Weiters kann ein Vorgehen auch eine Maßnahme sein, die gegen jemanden gerichtet ist:

- Das Vorgehen gegen die Internet-Kriminalität

Das ist aber leicht daran zu erkennen, dass hier immer das Wort *»gegen«* verwendet wird.

Answer (score 2):

Beide Begriffe bezeichnen einen Prozess, der von einem Zustand zu einem anderen führt.

Ein *Verfahren* ist dabei eher ein Prozess, der standardisiert ist und festen Regeln folgt, meistens auch "in Serie", also in vielen Fällen wiederholt genau gleich abläuft. (*Gerichtsverfahren*, *Tailor-Verfahren*, *Bessemer-Verfahren*...)

Demgegenüber steht das *Vorgehen*, das ebenfalls einen Prozeß beschreibt, der aber dem jeweiligen aktuellen Problem und auch der aktuellen Situation u.U. *taktisch* und dynamisch angepasst wird. Da die "Länge" des Prozesses nicht definiert ist, kann ein Vorgehen auch eine einzelne Handlungsweise sein.